# UDP or TCP hole punching to connect two peers (each one behind a router)

Tags: networking, tcp, netcat, udp, tcp-ip

I'm trying to connect directly (without 3rd party server) my computer to a friend's computer. We are both behind a ISP router, and would like (as a challenge!) to connect *without modifying the router configuration*.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545461/tcp-based-hole-punching/39581596#39581596) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420281/59989), we tried both TCP hole punching:

```
myself$ nc -p 7777 public-ip-friend 8888
friend$ nc -p 8888 public-ip-myself 7777
```

and UDP hole punching:

```
myself$ nc -u -p 7777 public-ip-friend 8888
friend$ nc -u -p 8888 public-ip-myself 7777
```

but none of them worked.

**How to solve this?**

Note: VPS (not behind a NAT) <--> my home computer (still behind router) works with the same method.

Comment: How are you synchronizing the requests? Do you see anything over `tcpdump`, e.g. RST packets?

Comment: Where should I do tcpdump @cherdt? On each one's computer? On the router (I don't know if it's possible to do that?)? What tcpdump command would you do in this example?

Comment: [pwnat](https://samy.pl/pwnat/) uses an interesting technique of setting up a TCP connection in a client-server style where the server is behind a NAT and doesn't require a third-party host to set up the connection as it uses ICMP messages.

Comment: @TorinCarey do you confirm that [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421993/59989) is the reason why it didn't work? How does pwnat works then to guess that srcip 7777 is rewritten to 55183 (in my example) by the NAT?

Comment: @Basj AFAIK your answer is spot on. As for pwnat, the main objective is for the server to learn the IP address and port of a connecting client. The server periodically sends an ICMP echo to a non-existent address, which the client creates an ICMP packet looking like a response to this echo in the eyes of the router, containing the client's IP address.

Comment: @Basj Wikipedia has a [good article on NAT traversal techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal#Techniques).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes the commands given in the question will work, but sometimes it won't.

Here is the reason.

Let's say:

- my computer IP on my local network: 192.168.1.10
- my home public IP: 203.0.113.10
- my friend's public IP: 198.51.100.27

When doing this on my computer:

```
myself$ nc -u -p 7777  198.51.100.27 8888
```

we have, before NAT translation:

```
srcip          srcport         destip            destport
192.168.1.10   7777            198.51.100.27     8888
```

but after the home router NAT translation we have:

```
srcip          srcport         destip            destport
203.0.113.10   55183(*)        198.51.100.27     8888
```

i.e. the source IP is rewritten by the NAT **but also the source port**.

So a "hole" will indeed be created in my home firewall (accepting traffic from my friend 198.51.100.27), but for port 55183, and **not for port** 7777.

This explains why it fails when my friend does:

```
friend$ nc -u -p 8888 203.0.113.10 7777
```

---

Note (*): In some cases the router might keep srcport=7777 instead of rewriting it to a random port like 55183.
It this case, the solution given in the question might work. But this is random behaviour!