# UDP hole punching with a third party

Tags: networking, netcat, udp

I am now convinced that direct "UDP hole punching" between 2 people each of them behind a NAT, without a 3rd party server is really difficult / sometimes impossible (see [question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421471/udp-or-tcp-hole-punching-to-connect-two-peers-each-one-behind-a-router) and my answer below).

**So, how to do a UDP hole punching *with* a 3rd party server?**

Example:

```
peerA$ nc -u -p 7777 serverIP 8888
```

Now this packet is translated by peerA's NAT from `localnetworkIP` to `peerApublicIP` and the source port is translated from 7777 to 55123.

Now the server sees this packet arriving and remembers peerA's public IP + port 55123. It gives these information (peerA's public IP + 55123) to peerB, and vice versa (the similar process described before happens for peerB, and server remembers peerB's publicIP + source port that has been translated by peerB's NAT from 8888 to 42000).

Now peerA can do this

```
peerA$ nc -u -p 7777 peerBpublicIP 8888    # will be dropped by peerB but at least it will 
                                           # punch a hole in peerA's firewall, port 55123
```

and peerB knows that, to connect peerA, he has to use port destination 55123 (this info was given by server):

```
peerB$ nc -u -p 8888 peerApublicIP 55123
```

---

Question: **this seems to work under the following assumption:**

If

```
peerA$ nc -u -p 7777 serverIP 8888
```

gets its source port translated from 7777 to 55123, **then**

```
peerA$ nc -u -p 7777 peerBpublicIP 8888
```

**Will also get source port 7777 translated to 55123.**

**But is this really true on most routers?**

If not (example: when connecting to server, NAT translates 7777 to 55123, but when connecting to peerB, NAT translates 7777 to 51098), how is UDP hole punching working?

**TL;DR**: More generally, how to do an UDP hole punching with just `netcat`, involving peerA, peerB, and a server (the latter used only at the beginning, and not later)?

**Note**: I already read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching#Flow), but it's not obvious if the port translation is done *in the same way* when connecting server and then peerB.

Comment: If you're going to involve a third party, might as well use a $5 VPS and go through OpenVPN. Otherwise you'll just have to keep shooting at random ports until you find a match. Or see if you can disable this randomization in your router. If your ISP is forcing it due to shared IPv4, maybe you could go via IPv6?

Comment: Yes @frostschutz I already have a vps this part is ok. Let's say both peers are on a public WiFi hotspot (e.g. in a bar / cafe), so we don't habe access to NAT configuration, nor ipv6 access.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) describes one UDP hole punching algorithm in detail. And [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-STUN-and-UDP-hole-punching) are some more well-known algorithms with names.

Comment: @dirkt: I mentioned this article at the end of my question; my question is about something not really explained in that article.